# How can I read the last 2 lines of a file in batch script

Tags: file, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a Java program that appends new builds information in the last two lines of a file. 
How can I read them in batch file?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: If you have access to the Windows Resource Kit, I would definitely use [`tail`](http://www.windows-commandline.com/tail-command-for-windows/) to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will solve the problem, where someFile.txt is the file where you want to read the lines from:

```
for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^< someFile.txt') do set /a lines=%%i
echo %lines%
set /a startLine=%lines% - 2
more /e +%startLine% someFile.txt > temp.txt
set vidx=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (temp.txt) do (
    SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
    set localVar!vidx!=%%A
)
echo %localVar1%
echo %localVar2%
del temp.txt
```

Comment: worked perfectly. I needed last 4 lines. I could adapt this easily.

Comment: `echo %localVar1%` and `echo %localVar2%` don't work. I've added a new solution to print directly.

Answer (score 7):

This code segment do the trick...

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in (someFile.txt) do (
   set "lastButOne=!lastLine!"
   set "lastLine=%%a"
)
echo %lastButOne%
echo %lastLine%
```

**EDIT**: *Complete TAIL.BAT added*

This method may be modified in order to get a larger number of lines, that may be specified by a parameter. The file below is **tail.bat**:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Tail command in pure Batch: Tail.bat filename numOfLines
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

for /F "delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
   set /A i=%2, j=%2-1
   for /L %%j in (!j!,-1,1) do (
      set "lastLine[!i!]=!lastLine[%%j]!
      set /A i-=1
   )
   set "lastLine[1]=%%a"
)
for /L %%i in (%2,-1,1) do if defined lastLine[%%i] echo !lastLine[%%i]!
```

**2ND EDIT**: *New version of TAIL.BAT added*

The version below is more efficient:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Tail command in pure Batch, version 2: Tail.bat filename numOfLines
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

set /A firstTail=1, lastTail=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
   set /A lastTail+=1, lines=lastTail-firstTail+1
   set "lastLine[!lastTail!]=%%a"
   if !lines! gtr %2 (
      set "lastLine[!firstTail!]="
      set /A firstTail+=1
   )
)
for /L %%i in (%firstTail%,1,%lastTail%) do echo !lastLine[%%i]!
```

Comment: Nice way without complication or temp file. Would be trickier with more lines to echo though.

Comment: I think a headache is coming... ;)

Comment: The 2nd edit is not working in Windows 11.

Answer (score 1):

```
::change the values bellow with a relevant ones.
set "file=C:\some.file"
set "last_lines=2"


for /f %%a in ('findstr /R /N "^" "%file%" ^| find /C ":"') do @set lines=%%a
set /a m=lines-last_line
more +%m% "%file%"
```

Directly from the command line:

```
C:\>set "file=C:\some.file"
C:\>set "last_lines=5"
C:\>(for /f %a in ('findstr /R /N "^" "%file%" ^| find /C ":"') do @set lines=%a)&@set /a m=lines-last_lines&call more +%m% "%file%"
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a modified answer of @joshi since their lines don't work:

```
echo %localVar1%
echo %localVar2%
```

So it's like this

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^< %1') do set /a lines=%%i
::echo %lines%
set /a startLine=%lines% - %2
more /e +%startLine% %1 | find /v ""
```

Call it with `Tail.bat file lines`. The last call of `find` prevents `more` to keep the file opened when doesn't fit the screen, so `find` forces to print out everything from stdin to stdout.