# copy latest four files using batch file

Tags: batch-file, window

I want to copy latest 4 SQL backup files from Directory. Now I have a code, this one copy most latest one file but I want to copy latest four files .

My From location is: `E:\BackUp`
Destination location is: `D:\BackUp`

Code:

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "E:\BackUp\*.bak" /B /O:D /S') DO SET NewestFile=%%I
copy "%NewestFile%" "D:\BackUp"
```

And I also need batch file for copy all files where created date is today date .
Have used "`/d`" but i can't get correct result?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
:: Variables are A, B, C, D
DIR "E:\BackUp\*.bak" /B /O:D /S > filelist.tmp
3<filelist.tmp (
  for %%a in (A B C D) do (
    set /p %%a=<&3
  )
)
del filelist.tmp
:: Newest File
copy "%A%" "D:\BackUp" 
:: Second Newest File
copy "%B%" "D:\BackUp" 
:: Thirst Newest File
copy "%C%" "D:\BackUp" 
:: Fourth Newest File
copy "%D%" "D:\BackUp"
```

As for copying every file created today, post that as a separate question on SO.

Comment: hi @monacraft have used your code but it will copy oldest 4 files ,it not copy latest 4 files..

Answer (score 0):

You may use the same approach of "Tail.bat" program, as described in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416341/how-can-i-read-last-2-lines-of-a-file-in-batch-script/27429851#27429851):

**EDIT**: *Modified as requested in comments*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A firstTail=1, lastTail=0

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir "E:\BackUp\*.bak" /B /O:D /S') do (
   set /A lastTail+=1, lines=lastTail-firstTail+1
   set "lastLine[!lastTail!]=%%a"
   if !lines! gtr 4 (
      set "lastLine[!firstTail!]="
      set /A firstTail+=1
   )
)
for /L %%i in (%firstTail%,1,%lastTail%) do (
   for /F "delims=_" %%a in ("!lastLine[%%i]!") do (
      copy "!lastLine[%%i]!" "D:\BackUp\%%a.bak"
   )
)
```

Comment: Hi @Aachini  i have another one requirement i want to rename this four file also,example The file name will be Database1_02082015.bak, Database2_02082015.bak, Database3_02082015.bak, Database3_02082015.bak  some thing like this,i want to remove after "_" ,after removed the file name should be Database1.bak,Database2.bak,Database3.bak,Database4.bak  how can i achieve this please help me..

Comment: Hi @Aachini have deleted my new question sorry for that, have test your modified code but no file are copied ,error msg only showing error msg is"The Filename,Directoty name or Volume label syntax is incorrect.